# setlocale and getlocale in lumen 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I was trying to localize my application and in the middleware, I am getting the locale from the request object. Now I need to access this outside the controller while running a job.

As from the documentation, I can see that the app() can hold this data. But `app()->setLocale()`  and `app()->getLocale()` is not working for me in lumen 5.6.

Ant help will be much appreciable.

Answer (score 8):

Finally, I found the answer. There is a translator object in the framework and you have to use the following code to set a locale

```
app('translator')->setLocale($locale);
```

and to get a locale in anywhere in the application using

```
app('translator')->getLocale();
```

Comment: On Lumen 8, app()->setLocale($locale); works.